# Changing the way org-links behave on clicking only when it's a text file

Tags: org-mode

I'd like to change the way org-links behave on clicking only when it's a text file etc.

i.e. I'd like to have org-links opens up a new frame with the buffer of the link in it only when it's the link of a .txt, .el, or .png file. I already found [a snippet below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881649/how-to-force-org-mode-to-open-a-link-in-another-frame) that basically does this, but I can't figure out how to assign this command to the left click so that it runs the command only when it's on org-links. How can I do that?

```
(defun zin/org-open-other-frame ()
  "Jump to bookmark in another frame. See `bookmark-jump' for more."
  (interactive)
  (let ((org-link-frame-setup (acons 'file 'find-file-other-frame org-link-frame-setup)))
    (org-open-at-point)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```lisp
(require 'org)

(defun my-find-file-fn (file)
"If the filename extension of FILE ends in `.txt' or `.el' or `.png', then use
`find-file-other-frame'; otherwise, use `find-file-other-window'.  The three file
extensions txt/el/png are hard-coded into the let-bound variable `regex'."
  (let* (
      ;; regexp-matchp-fn from:  https://github.com/kentaro/auto-save-buffers-enhanced
      ;; regexp-matchp-fn modified by @sds:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/20343715/2112489
      (regexp-matchp-fn
        (lambda (regexps string)
          (and string
             (catch 'matched
               (let ((inhibit-changing-match-data t))
                 (dolist (regexp regexps)
                   (when (string-match regexp string)
                     (throw 'matched t))))))))
      (ext (file-name-extension file))
      (regex '("txt" "el" "png")))
    (if (funcall regexp-matchp-fn regex ext)
      (find-file-other-frame file)
      (find-file-other-window file))))

(setq org-link-frame-setup '(
  (vm . vm-visit-folder-other-frame)
  (vm-imap . vm-visit-imap-folder-other-frame)
  (gnus . org-gnus-no-new-news)
  (file . my-find-file-fn)
  (wl . wl-other-frame)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try customizing either `display-buffer-alist` (for an Emacs-wide setting) or `org-file-apps` (for an Org-mode-only setting).

Assuming you want an Org-mode-only setting, try:

```
(defun ph/find-file-new-frame (filename)
  (select-frame (make-frame))
  (find-file filename))

(add-to-list 'org-file-apps
  '("\\.\\(?:txt\\|el\\|png\\)\\'" . (ph/find-file-new-frame file)))
```